# Webmatrix check if item is in collection, return boolean

Tags: c#, razor, webmatrix

```
   @{ 
        Layout = "~/_SiteLayout.cshtml";
        Page.Title = "Training";
        var positionID = "";
        positionID = Request.QueryString["ID"];
        var db = Database.Open("Training");
        var courselist = db.Query("SELECT title, ID FROM courses");
        var selectedCourses = db.Query("SELECT course_id from positioncourses WHERE position_id = @0", positionID);
}
        <h1>Select or deselect courses for this position:</h1>
            @foreach(var item in courselist){
                <label for="courseID">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="courseID" value="@item.id" checked="@(selectedCourses.Contains(item.ID))" /> @item.title

                </label>
            }
```

The above codeblock results in:

"Compiler Error Message: CS1973: 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' has no applicable method named 'Contains' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax."

What is causing the error? I am not advanced enough to decipher from the error message itself.

Comment: checked="@(selectedCourses.Contains(item.ID))" //should return true or false, which results in checkbox being ticked or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is caused by the fact that the Query method returns a collection of dynamic types and you cannot use extension methods on dynamic. You have to cast the dynamic to a strong type at compile time. The following should work:

```
    // as before
    var courselist = db.Query("SELECT title, ID FROM courses");
    var selectedCourses = db.Query("SELECT course_id from positioncourses WHERE position_id = @0", positionID).Select(c => (int)c.course_id);
}
<h1>Select or deselect courses for this position:</h1>
@foreach(var item in courselist.Select(i => (int)i.ID)){
    <label for="courseID">
        <input type="checkbox" name="courseID" value="@item.id" checked="@(selectedCourses.Contains(item))" /> @courselist.First(c => c.ID == item).title
    </label>
}
```

Notice the casting to `int` that converts the `selectedCourses` from `IEnumerable<dynamic>` to `IEnumerable<int>` and the same again to separate the `IDs` in the `courselist` from the `title` so that you are comparing `ints` with `ints`.

Comment: When I remove the .id from value="@item.id", it works perfectly. With it, throws error "'int' does not contain a definition for 'id' and no extension method 'id' accepting a first argument of type 'int' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?), but still returns the correct value. Your help was invaluable.

Answer (score 0):

You have used db.Query, db.Query returns a collection of items (IEnumerable), if you're trying to return one result change it to db.QuerySingle.

```
var selectedCourses = db.QuerySingle("SELECT course_id from positioncourses WHERE position_id = @0", positionID);
```